# How can I call an expect script with a sequence of arguments

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, expect

I have an expect script that looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set path_start [lindex $argv 0]
set host [lindex $argv 1]
spawn ssh root@$host telnet jpaxdp
expect {\-> }

set fh [open ${path_start}${host} r]
while {[gets $fh line] != -1} {
    send "$line\r"
    expect {\-> }
}
close $fh

send "exit\r"
expect eof
```

and I call it like `./script.sh cmds_ cc1`, now my hosts are numbered 1 - 8 and I  tried to call the script like `./script cmds_ cc[1-8]` but that didn't work as the script interpreted **host[1-8]** as argument and showed me:

```
spawn ssh root@cc[1-8] telnet jpaxdp
ssh: Could not resolve hostname cc[1-8]: Name or service not known
couldn't open "cmds_cc[1-8]": no such file or directory
    while executing
"open ${path_start}${host} r"
    invoked from within
"set fh [open ${path_start}${host} r]"
    (file "./script.sh" line 7)
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: That's an Expect script, not a bash script.

Comment: There might be a command line utility that will recursively do calls like this. I would recommend another script that does so if quick Googling doesn't find you anything from Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cc[1-8]` is a filename wildcard, it looks for files that match that pattern. If there aren't any, the wildcard itself is kept in the argument list. To get a range of numbers, use `cc{1..8}`. And to run the command repeatedly, you need a `for` loop.

```
for host in cc{1..8}
do
    ./script.sh cmds_ "$host"
done
```